# Displaying an Alert box on receiving response from server in iphone SDK

Tags: iphone, multiview

On Iphone App start I start a background thread to receive some data from server .
where it allows the user to navigate through different views . I have to display an alert when I have a response from server regardless of current view of user . how this can be done ?
I think I have to notify my all views on receiving data ? please advise....

Regards

Rizwan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding an alert view in connectionDidFinishLoading delegate method is enough as below,

```
- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection {
        UIAlertView *alertBox=[[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Got response" message:@"Loading completed." delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
[alertBox show];
[alertBox release];
}
```

as the alertview will come to the top (works like a local notification).

But you have to make sure that the instance of the class from which you made the web service call and the NSUrlConnection object persists till the connection is finished loading. (not released or deallocated)

Answer (score 0):

No, there will be a method like connectionDidReceiveResponse or something else, which will be called when your background thread receives the data. Show this alert in that method and it will come up as soon as the data is received.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like something that should be in you appDelegate.

Answer (score 0):

An alert view will be shown on top of any other view regardless of the view hierarchy. So basically you will have to handle the response and display a uialertview which will be shown on top of any view. Handle the action on the alert view accordingly. There is no need for all the views to get this message. Just your main view controller/or object which is persistent throughout the lifetime of your application is enough.